# Android ACTION_VIDEO_CAPTURE Intent Crashes

Tags: android

I am using the following intent to invoke the camera and save the
recording as a specific name:

```
filepath = "/sdcard/testfolder/testvid.mp4";
File vidfile = new File(filepath);
Uri viduri = Uri.fromFile(vidfile);
Intent i = new
Intent(android.provider.MediaStore.ACTION_VIDEO_CAPTURE);
i.putExtra(android.provider.MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, viduri);
startActivity(i);
```

However the application keeps on crashing (The application has ....
stopped unexpectedly). But I noticed that the file has been saved with
the required name in the directory.

Any idea how can i resolve this? Basically I want to start the video
camera and save the subsequent recording in a specific directory and
name.

Thanks In Advance,
Perumal

Comment: Please post some logs. Also, try updating your question as to when exactly you get a crash. At the start/After you stop capturing etc.

Comment: i.putExtra(android.provider.MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, viduri); didn't work for me from android 2.3.3 it worked previously. May be a bug.

Answer (score 0):

Try with

```
startActivityForResult(i, 0);
```